# Selectively copying a data list in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking to selectively copy a list of data in Excel for the purposes of reducing the quantity.

In the first column I have Date/time and in the second column I have a data value, in this case it's electrical meter readings.

The data is currently given very 15 minutes and what I'm trying to do is reduce that to every hour.  i.e. effectively create a new column which extracts only the data from the original list for every hour (Also with no gaps in the rows, therefore condensing the length of the list).

Any advice much appreciated!

Comment: are you okay with having the readings accumulated? i.e all readings from 7:00 to 7:45 including would be summed into a single value

Comment: Is the reading cumulative, i.e: 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,9,10 or is the amount reset every time?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where have you run into problems?  This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code or complex formulas you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)